# Model table not getting auto created in mysql loopback 3

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am new to Loopback framework.
I have gone through getting started and model creation and tried creating test application.
I created application by command ->  `lb` 
 
and created mysql datasource by -> `lb datasource` 
 
and created  two models by -> `lb model` 
which are using mysql datasource.

```js
{
  "name": "Brand",
  "plural": "brands",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

so now when I start application by `npm start` and goto `localhost:3000/explorer` and try using any end point, I get following table not found error. 
`Unhandled error for request GET /api/brands: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'loop3.Brand' doesn't exist`

Does Loopback auto creates tables in database ?? Or I will have to create `autoMigrate` file for every model Or how it should be done please help..

**Answer:** 
thanks to @Diana, I created `script.js` file in `boot` directory and added following code

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  var db = app.datasources.mysqld;

  db.autoupdate(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('\nAutomigrate completed');
    // other code here
  });
};
```

It creates table as well as updates if any property has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the `automigrate` function to create the table schema in the database. You can add this in the boot script that it will get run every time you start the application. See this as an example:
https://github.com/ssh24/loopback-sandbox/blob/master/apps/mysql/mysql-101/server/boot/script.js

Please note that the `automigrate` function will drop the existing table and create it again. It means any existing data will be lost. `autoupdate` function can be used instead. See this documentation page for details: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html.

Comment: It worked after creating file in `boot` directory with `autoupdate` so now it also creates table and edits if any.